Confused as to when and how to round when performing Gaussian elimination with $n$ digits
Some exercises in computational mathematics ask us to represent numbers using only the $n$ most significant digits. While carrying out computations, I'm lost as to when and how to round the answer. Here is an example:

Consider the linear system $(Ax = b)$ given by:
\begin{aligned}
    0.004000x + 69.13y &= 69.17 \\
    4.281x - 5.230y &= 41.91
\end{aligned}
Solve the linear system using Gaussian elimination.
Important: Use floating-point arithmetic with 4 significant digits in all calculations for this exercise.

I start the exercise as follows:
$$m := 1070.25 = 4.281 / 0.004 = 1070.25.$$
Multiplying the first row of the matrix by $m$ and subtracting the result from the second row, I get the following:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0.004 & 69.13 & 69.17 \\
4.281 & -5.23 & 41.91
\end{pmatrix}
\sim
\begin{pmatrix}
0.004 & 69.13 & 69.17 \\
0 & -73991.6125 & -73987.2825
\end{pmatrix}
$$
As I must use $4$ digits per element, the result becomes
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0.004 & 69.13 & 69.17 \\
0 & -73992 & -73990
\end{pmatrix}$$
and the exercise continues...

Here are my doubts:

Computing the second entry of the second row involves the following steps:
$$r(-69.13m- 5.23) = r(-73986.3825 - 5.23) = r(-73991.6125) = -73992.$$
Is it correct to apply the rounding $r$ at the end? One alternative would be
$$r[r(-69.13m)-5.23] = r[r(-73986.3825) - 5.23] = r[-73990 - 5.23] = r[-73995.23] = -73995.$$
Yet another alternative is to round $m$ to $1070$ before starting the calculation i.e.
$$r[r(-69.13 \ r[m]) - 5.23] = r[r(-73969.1) - 5.23] = r[-73970 - 5.23] = r[-73975.23] = -73975.$$

(This question is applicable only if the answer to the above is to round only at the end of the computation) If matrix had three rows, should we wait until we solve the system to round, or should we round after computing each matrix $A^{(k)}$ corresponding to the $k$-th step of Gaussian elimination?

The convention is to always round to the nearest integer, right? Alternatives would be to round up or down.



Note: before writing this answer I stumbled across this post solving an analogous problem. The OP rounds up at the end, but no questions or comments are made as to the correctness of this, and the only answer does not round at all.

I think the problem is "round first", then continue. Just imagine your computer always gives you four digits and can't store anything more.
